# Include OpenSSL into Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, openssl

Is there any fully working example how to include OpenSSL library to Android NDK to be used in C++ code? It seems to me that most of examples are over-complicating that.

Comment: There are static link libs floating around for OpenSSL on Android. Have you tried looking around at all? On Android 6+, Google abandoned OpenSSL in favor of BoringSSL (an OpenSSL fork), and there can be interference trying to use OpenSSL dynamically on BoringSSL devices.

Comment: If you are looking for a script to build the Android libs, you should not look further than the official site: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android, but it's easier to find prebuilt binaries, especially if you are on Windows.

Comment: Thank you for the BoringSSL, I'll take a look.
@AlexCohn Sorry, but it seems like security vulnerability to use prebuilt ssl library

Comment: Yes, the security considerations should not  be taken lightly

Comment: But I understand why people use prebuilt version. It's really pain to build it on windows

Comment: @RemyLebeau Just a note to your advice. Using BoringSSL would be a huge mistake, because Google states that it is not meant to be public and that they are not going to care about API consistency. Exact quatiotion `Although BoringSSL is an open source project, it is not intended for general use, as OpenSSL is.`

Comment: @JakubGruber I believe that your interpretation of the quotation is not correct *(sorry I didn't see your comment earlier)*. I would translate the [message](https://opensource.google.com/projects/boringssl) as follows: don't expect our fork to be a plug-and-play replacement for OpenSSL, don't impose it on people who need OpenSSL, don't use it as the SSL provider for your Linux distribution. They encourage you to pick up their code, and package it with your app (which is the natural practice for Android anyways). Google also prevents you from using the system BoringSSL libraries in your app.

Comment: another late comment: Android architecture ensures that there will be no interference between the BoringSSL libraries that are part of the platform (and serve system services), and whatever implementation you choose for your app, even if you use shared libs.